# "Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes" appears in comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design

I have found a bug involving the "Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes" message.

1. After writing a comment, stay on the page until the comment is 5 minutes old.
2. Click the (still visible) "Edit" link.
3. Make a change to the comment and attempt to save the comment.
4. Note that the "Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes" message appears.
5. Click the "Cancel" link.
6. Click the (still visible) "Edit" link.

What happens is that the text in the edit box now has *xComments may only be edited for 5 minutes* appended to it several times.

[image: Comment bug]

Not sure if the solution is fixing the appended text or hiding the "Edit" link, but regardless, this is a bug that occurs on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: repro'ed: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YPHpa.png :) (@nicael there's another helpful flag :P)

Comment: Related case on MSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314852/993547

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were *obviously* using it wrong! One should click X first, before clicking cancel, d'oh...

[image: UX]

A fix is rolling out in the next build (build rev `2016.2.18.4180` on MSE/MSO, `2016.2.18.3267` on sites).